# How to take non-missing value associated with max index for each group using summarize_all

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I want to find the non-missing value of each group associated with the largest index value, for many columns.

I have gotten fairly close by using summarize_all with which.max but I am not sure how to remove the NAs from each vector before I find the latest value. I read about using na.rm in summarize_all with functions like mean but not sure how to incorporate similar functionality without a built in function. I have tried na.omit but it doesnt provide the solution I'm looking for.

```
a <- head(iris, 10)
a$num <- 1:10
a$grp <- c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d","d")
a[10, "Species"] <- NA
a %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(na.omit(.)[which.max(num)]))

grp   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   num
<chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int>
1 a             4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa      3
2 b             5.00        3.60         1.40       0.200 setosa      5
3 c             4.60        3.40         1.40       0.300 setosa      7
4 d             4.90        3.10         1.50       0.100 NA         10
```

I expect all the values in the Species column to be setosa, however the last value is NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking at all `num`, we may look only at those where the corresponding variable is not `NA`:

```
a %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(na.omit(.)[which.max(num[!is.na(.)])]))
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#   grp   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   num
#   <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int>
# 1 a              4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      3
# 2 b              5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      5
# 3 c              4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      7
# 4 d              4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     10
```

Comment: No need for `na.omit(.)`, `summarize_all(funs(.[which.max(num[!is.na(.)])]))` did the job.

Comment: Thanks @Julius Vainora! very helpful.

Comment: I have encountered an interesting issue with this approach. I ran the code above on my data set and I had a couple records that still had NAs. After much research it seems to have something to do with the order of the rows. You can see what I mean with the below example. `a <- head(iris, 15)
a$num <- 1:15
a$grp <- c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d")
a[c(12, 13), "Petal.Width"] <- NA
a <- a %>% arrange(c(1:11, 14, 13, 12, 15))
#a <- rbind(a, a[12:14, ])
#a[10, "Species"] <- NA
a %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(.[which.max(num[!is.na(.)])]))`

Comment: @HunterClark, I think it was a mistake to drop `na.omit` after all. What about `funs(na.omit(.)[which.max(num[!is.na(.)])])`? Does seem to work. Indeed dropping `na.omit` introduced mess..

Comment: Thanks again @Julius. that seems to work. I dont understand why the issue came up though...

Comment: @HunterClark, `num[!is.na(.)]` is a subvector of `num` where the corresponding variable (`.`) is not `NA`. So, this subvector may be shorter than `num`. Then `which.max` returns an index in this potentially shorter subvector. Then doing `.[which.max(num[!is.na(.)])]` was wrong because the corresponding variable wasn't shortened before subsetting. `na.omit(.)` aligns it with `num[!is.na(.)]`.

Comment: @Julius, ahhhhhh. thanks much for the clarification. Would you like to adjust your answer or should I edit the main post to update the information?

Comment: @HunterClark, everything's great with your question and I've already erased the mistake from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you use a data.table approach, you can try:

```
library (data.table)
a = data.table (a)
a [is.finite (Species), by = grp, .SD [which.max (num) ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also approach this a little differently and complete the `NA` case first:

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  fill(Species) %>% 
  filter(num == max(num))

tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   grp [4]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   num grp  
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int> <chr>
1          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      3 a    
2          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      5 b    
3          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      7 c    
4          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     10 d
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mako212. While your answer works great for the example case, in looking into fill it may cause difficulties if the index isn't sorted previously. Because of this I will opt for Julius' answer but I will keep fill in mind for the future.